# excel logic error, everything passes the logic test

Tags: excel, if-statement, logic

```
=IF(D3>0, G2+(D3/111.3), G2-(D3/111.3))
```

So i'm trying to run this small line of code in excel but for whatever values the result always comes up true on the logic operator. for example let's say d3 is -9, it will run the first equation when really it should run the second. Any ideas?

[Hopefully the image helps describe what is goin on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjQ1v.png)

Comment: Seems to me everything is working fine, because your result is always positive.

Answer (score 0):

might be the value in cell (d3) is text formatted?.

check this formatting part .

also, try this if sheet1.range("d3") > 0....Just use full path name (sheet, followed by range /cell name)...

try your luck...

Comment: d3 text formatted? Sorry, I haven't used excel much be got an assignment that requires it so i'm not to familiar with how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You only need this one

```
=G2+(D3/111.3)
```

With your formula:

```
=IF(D3>0, G2+(D3/111.3), G2-(D3/111.3))
#D3 = -9, G2 = 100
#IF([-9]>0, 100+([-9]/111.3), 100-([-9]/111.3))
#IF([-9]>0, 100+0.080, 100-(-0.080))
#IF([-9]>0, 100+0.080, 100+0.080
```

Which make you confuse why it always add the value of `D3`